# Create Global Nav links with Audience via powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have a powershell script that will allow me to add links to the Global navigation in my O365 Sharepoint sites, but I would like to add "Audience" limitations so only members of specific AD groups can see certain links.

I am using a variation of the script provided by 
Vadim Gremyachev here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/167545/68868.

```
Function AddNavigationNode([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNode]$ParentNode,[string]$Title,[string]$Url){
   $context = $ParentNode.Context
   $Node = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation 
   $Node.Title = $Title
   $Node.Url = $Url 
   $Node.AsLastNode = $true
   $context.Load($ParentNode.Children.Add($Node))
   $context.ExecuteQuery()
}
```

I do not see any properties of the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation type to allow me to enter the AD group.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint the navigation itself has no permissions to be set. Rather every entry (as long as the target is part of SharePoint) is security trimmed by it's target.

As a SharePoint-User I will never see navigation-entries to which I am unable to navigate. (As long as one of the default SharePoint navigation-providers is used, that is.)

Comment: Can you please explain the statement "As long as one of the default SharePoint navigation-providers is used, that is"?  What I am seeing is that I add a link to another Sharepoint site in the Global Navigation, and all users are able to see the link, even if they are not a member of a sharepoint group that has been given permission to view, edit, modify or other to the target site.  The only way I found to hide the link is to add an AD group to the "Audience" field on the link properties.

Comment: Security Trimming only works within the site collection.  If a link in the global nav points to a site in a different site collection, it is not trimmed automatically, it must have an Audience assigned to it to hide it from others who do not have access.  That is what I am trying to do.